# How to toggle parent background?

Tags: jquery

I have simple table with check box. When it is checked - i need to change color of row.

```
<tr height="35">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ></td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Surname</td>
</tr>
```

At the moment i do it with

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

But i think the `.parent().parent()` is not a good idea... And also is some way to toggle background? Maybe somehow on change ant after is checked or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
         $(this).parents("tr:first").css("background-color", "red");
  });
```

reference : http://api.jquery.com/parents/

demo :   http://jsfiddle.net/qGZPP/

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to make a toggle background color on check box click.

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var self = jQuery(this);
    var parentTr = self.closest("tr");
    if(this.checked)
      parentTr.css('background-color', 'red');
    else 
      parentTr.css('background-color', 'default-color or empty if no default color');
});
```

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RLEgY/2/)**